# Kivy multiple selection with checkboxes

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I'm trying to create a view using Kivy that has a list of options that are all selected by default, and the user can choose to deselect some entries (by clicking on the checkbox or anywhere on the row).

Clicking on the label part of the row item works, but I noticed that clicking on the checkbox doesn't change the selection which I can't work out how to solve (I tried a few different state bindings, I left them commented out in the example code)

Here is a quick example showing what I've tried.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.selectableview import SelectableView
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButtonBehavior
from kivy.adapters.models import SelectableDataItem
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
#: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#: import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<MyListItem>:
    height: 50

    on_state: root.is_selected = args[1] == "down"
    state: "down" if root.is_selected else "normal"

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10

        CheckBox:
            on_state: root.is_selected = args[1] == "down"
            state: "down" if root.is_selected else "normal"
            # on_state: root.state = args[1]
            # state: root.state

        Label:
            text: root.name

<Page>:
    orientation: "vertical"

    ListView:
        id: LV
        adapter: ListAdapter(data=root.data, cls=Factory.MyListItem, args_converter=root.args_converter, selection_mode="multiple", propagate_selection_to_data=True)

    Button:
        size_hint_y: None
        text: "print selection"
        on_press: print(LV.adapter.selection)
""")

class MyListItem(ToggleButtonBehavior, SelectableView, BoxLayout):
    name = StringProperty()

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(name=%r)" % (type(self).__name__, self.name)

    def on_state(self, me, state):
        print me, state
        if state == "down":
            self.select()
        else:
            self.deselect()
        # self.is_selected = state == "down"

class DataItem(SelectableDataItem):
    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
        super(DataItem, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(name=%r, is_selected=%r)" % (type(self).__name__, self.name, self.is_selected)


class Page(BoxLayout):
    data = ListProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Page, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [DataItem("Item {}".format(i), is_selected=True) for i in range(10)]

    def args_converter(self, index, data_item):
        return {
            "index": index,
             "name": data_item.name,
        }


class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Page()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ExampleApp().run()
```

I'm using Kivy `v1.9.1-dev`

---

**Edit:** I worked out how to get all the entries pre-selected, I've updated the code and took that part of the question out.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else has the the question I point to the right url:

You should consider the new RecycleView, which has all the functionality you request. Look here for a sample: [Kivy: alternative to deprecated features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43561532/kivy-alternative-to-deprecated-features/43618168#43618168)