# Kivy: alternative to deprecated features

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am trying adapt this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617901/kivy-multiple-selection-with-checkboxes) but I am still the first step as I don't understand most of the features called like like [SelectableDataItem](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.adapters.models.html), [Adapter](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.adapters.adapter.html#kivy.adapters.adapter.Adapter), [ListAdapter](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.adapters.listadapter.html?highlight=listadapter#module-kivy.adapters.listadapter) or [SelectableView](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.selectableview.html).

When I looked them up on the kivy website, I have seen that they are listed as deprecated. I don't find any alternatives to these features on the Kivy website and I don't want to build an app with deprecated features.

So my question is: what are the alternative to these four features or in other terms, how should I modify the code so that it doesn't call deprecated features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [RecycleView](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html)
I wrote an example of what you might want, with RecycleView

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior



items = [
    {"text": "white",    "selected": 'normal', "input_data": ["some","random","data"]},
    {"text": "lightblue","selected": 'normal', "input_data": [1,6,3]},
    {"text": "blue",     "selected": 'normal', "input_data": [64,16,9]},
    {"text": "gray",     "selected": 'normal', "input_data": [8766,13,6]},
    {"text": "orange",   "selected": 'normal', "input_data": [9,4,6]},
    {"text": "yellow",   "selected": 'normal', "input_data": [852,958,123]},
    {"text": "white",    "selected": 'normal', "input_data": ["some","random","data"]},
    {"text": "lightblue","selected": 'normal', "input_data": [1,6,3]},
    {"text": "blue",     "selected": 'normal', "input_data": [64,16,9]},
    {"text": "gray",     "selected": 'normal', "input_data": [8766,13,6]},
    {"text": "orange",   "selected": 'normal', "input_data": [9,4,6]},
    {"text": "yellow",   "selected": 'normal', "input_data": [852,958,123]}
]



class MyViewClass(RecycleDataViewBehavior, BoxLayout):

    text = StringProperty("")
    index = None

    def set_state(self,state,app):
        app.root.ids.rv.data[self.index]['selected'] = state

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        self.index = index
        return super(MyViewClass, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)



class MyRecycleView(RecycleView):

    data = items

    def print_data(self,data):
        print([item['input_data'] for item in data if item['selected'] == 'down'])



KV = '''

<MyViewClass>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    CheckBox:
        on_state: root.set_state(self.state,app)
    Label:
        text: root.text

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    MyRecycleView:
        id: rv
        viewclass: 'MyViewClass'
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            default_size: None, dp(56)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
    Button:
        size_hint_y: 0.1
        text: "Print data"
        on_release: rv.print_data(rv.data)

'''



class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        root = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return root


Test().run()
```

Comment: Super, this is really helping me, thanks a lof @EL3PHANTEN! I am trying to adapt this to display items, each with a text of about 500 words. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @Enora you are wellcome. A label with 500 words maybe. In a boxlayout every widget is the same size. So in that case you would preset the height in RecycleBoxLayout, default_size: None, dp(100), or whatever is high enough.

Comment: Well, it doesn't change anything. The height doesn't increase but the texts don't reflow.

Comment: @Enora will every widget be the same size, or will the amount of text decide the widget size? I mean if you use boxlayout every box will be the same height. Which layout will you use?

Comment: No, unfortunately not all texts will be the same length so if the size can be set by the longest test (or if there were a way to use a scrollable label with the recycle view) that would be great! Please have a look at the edit in the question: I use a boxlayout.

Comment: @Enora yea :) dont edit it so much so it turns out I didnt answer it :D. Anyways, how about a textinut that you cant edit? That would be scrollable

Comment: Sorry for the edit, I've removed it. You did a great job answering my question, and I am well aware that what I was asking in the comment is an extra. Yes, TextInput is coming close to what I want, so I will go for it. Thanks so much for your kindness and your extra time!

Comment: @Enora hehe good. When users search for the same problem, they wont get confused. And you are wellcome. Happy to help. You can allways place a new question, that goes more specifically into scrollable labels, or size adapting lables.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, therefore this way:

When you are using much text, have rstDocument in mind, which has much more possibilities.  Most of Python online documentation is based on restrctured Text. And just in case you decide to go this way, use the retext Editor for rst.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeView
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeViewLabel
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeViewNode
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.rst import RstDocument
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
import kivy


class TreeViewRst (RstDocument,TreeViewNode):
        pass

def update_size (event1,event2):
    event1.size = event1.viewport_size

txt ="""

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Mauris accumsan consequat justo, non aliquet sapien bibendum non. 
Nam quam risus, tempus quis lorem eu, sodales facilisis justo. 

Curabitur quis placerat ante. Phasellus tempor, libero vitae 
commodo accumsan, lorem metus eleifend velit, id dapibus ipsum ante sed massa. 
onec aliquam pellentesque pharetra. Praesent quis augue id elit facilisis euismod 
vel nec erat. Vestibulum nec dolor eget sem ullamcorper tempor id et dui. In a egestas massa.
Nulla vel augue non nisi varius varius.

"""

class TreeApp (App):
    def build (self):
        root = StackLayout()
        scroll = ScrollView(pos = (0, 0),size_hint=(1,0.78))
        body = TreeView(hide_root=True,indent_level=0,size_hint=(1,None))
        body.bind(minimum_height=body.setter('height'))
        intro = body.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text="Title",font_size=18))
        intro_diag = body.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text="Article"))
        long_txt = txt*10
        test = body.add_node(TreeViewRst(text=long_txt, size=(100,400)),parent=intro_diag)

        #test.bind(on_scroll_start=update_size)
        scroll.add_widget(body)
        root.add_widget(scroll)
        print(kivy.__version__)
        return root

Window.size = (360,640)
tree = TreeApp()
tree.run()
```