# Kivy App crashes on Android KitKat ( Kivy Launcher)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kivy

My other apps work fine on [Kivy Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kivy.pygame) but this one crashes on the loading screen (sometimes I don't even see the text loading before the crash). Because the crash happens during the loading, Kivy Launcher doesn't create a log in `MyApp/.kivy/logs`. So I don't have any log.

My phone is a Samsung S3 with Kitkat.

I copied the folder `Python36\Lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\recycleview` (maybe the culprit) in my app folder on my phone, but my app still crashes. 
This is the app (many thanks to [El3phanten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43564134/3154274)):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior

items = [
    {"text": "white",    "selected": 'normal', "input_data": ["some","random","data"]},
    {"text": "lightblue","selected": 'normal', "input_data": [1,6,3]}
]

class MyViewClass(RecycleDataViewBehavior, BoxLayout):

    text = StringProperty("")
    index = None

    def set_state(self,state,app):
        app.root.ids.rv.data[self.index]['selected'] = state

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        self.index = index
        return super(MyViewClass, self).refresh_view_attrs(rv, index, data)

class MyRecycleView(RecycleView):

    data = items

    def print_data(self,data):
        print([item['input_data'] for item in data if item['selected'] == 'down'])

KV = '''

<MyViewClass>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    CheckBox:
        on_state: root.set_state(self.state,app)
    Label:
        text: root.text

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    MyRecycleView:
        id: rv
        viewclass: 'MyViewClass'
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            default_size: None, dp(56)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
    Button:
        size_hint_y: 0.1
        text: "Print data"
        on_release: rv.print_data(rv.data)

'''

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        root = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return root


Test().run()
```

---

Edit:
I am now getting the log. I tried @KeyWeeUsr solution but still the module isn't found.

My app folder is now structured in this way:

```
my_app/:
   -main.py
   -android.txt
   -kivy/
      -uix/
         -recycleview/
            -__init__.py
            -datamodel.py
            -layout.py
            -views.py
```

Here is the log:

```
[INFO              ] Logger: Record log in /storage/emulated/0/kivy/del/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-04-27_2.txt
[INFO              ] Kivy: v1.9.1
[INFO              ] Python: v2.7.2 (default, Mar 20 2016, 23:30:13) 
[GCC 4.8]
[INFO              ] Factory: 179 symbols loaded
[WARNING           ] stderr: /data/data/org.kivy.pygame/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/image/img_pygame.py:13: RuntimeWarning: import cdrom: No module named cdrom
[WARNING           ] stderr: (ImportError: No module named cdrom)
[INFO              ] Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_pygame, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[WARNING           ] stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
[WARNING           ] stderr:   File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
[WARNING           ] stderr:     from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
[WARNING           ] stderr: ImportError: No module named recycleview
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the log, I use the app [LogCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat&hl=en) (it requires root access)

I couldn't get Kivy Launcher to work because the version is still in 1.9.1

I ended up having to use Buildozer to package the app (I had to create a [dual boot](https://www.lifewire.com/ultimate-windows-7-ubuntu-linux-dual-boot-guide-2200653) with ubuntu 17.04, then install python 3.6, [kivy](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html) and [buildozer](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html#buildozer))

I had to modify the buildozer.spec file like this:

```
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = kivy==master
```

Do not modify this line (even if it's tempting!):

```
# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an app which uses RecyclerView too, and I run it on Android without a problem (by building a package, not copying the folder, I use Kivy 1.9.2dev0)

In order to know what really cause the crash, you need to read the log when your app is running.

1. Plug your phone and make sure it's listed via `adb devices`
2. Install the app via `adb -d install -r abc.apk`
3. Check the log, `msg for filter` is your package name `org.test.myapp` sort of things

   - Mac or Linux: `adb logcat | grep “msg for filter”`
   - Windows: `adb logcat | FINDSTR “msg for filter"`
4. You will get the real log

Comment: I would like to avoid packaging the app (it's still in beta and I find it convenient to be able to edit the file directly on my phone). Please have a look at the log at the bottom of my question.

Comment: I just packaged the app with buildozer but I am still getting the same error "ImportError: No module named recycleview". Not sure if it could be the cause but do you use python 3.6?

Answer (score 0):

Kivy apps running on android (yes even the launcher) are supposed to debug with `adb logcat` because the real output from the application therefore even all crashes, library loading fails and so on are there, in the `logcat`.

The log available in `.kivy` file is pure Kivy log and includes nothing about how the APK was launched, how the Window was teared down or if there was some problem with loading e.g. the Python interpreter itself. → No logcat, no clear solution.

Anyway, there's a way how to make a custom Kivy Launcher with:

- https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/pull/891 (already in master)
- https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/pull/981

But the second change needs to be applied as it's needed for the launcher.

You can however try to place the folder in your app folder correctly i.e.:

```
my_app
|
|- main.py
|
|- kivy/uix/recycleview (multiple folders, not ONE)
```

or paste here the log.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have to tell you that I am pretty new to python and Kivy and most of what I read on the link are like chinese for me. I will have a closer and try to understand how to make a custom kivy launcher. I tried you solution (placing the folder kivy/uix/recycleview in my app folder instead of directly the recycleview folder as I have done, but the app still crashes with "No module named recycleview".